# Maven assembly Include too many dependencies in a ZIP

Tags: maven, build, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Maven multi-module project. In one module, we create a ZIP with maven-assembly-plugin plugin. The configuration for this:

```
<baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>    
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>           
        <excludes>
            <exclude>
                com.sample.blabla:test-core-client
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
```

And the pom config for this:

```
<execution>
    <id>make-service-client-with-dependencies-zip</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>${service-client-with-dependencies.zip.filename}</finalName>
            <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/zip</outputDirectory>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test-service-client-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Unfortunately the created ZIP contains much more jar-s, that we would like... for example: 37 X maven-XXX JAR, a lot of spring jars, wagon jars,...etc.

But we wouldn't like to include these jars, just which necessary for runtime. How can we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven assembly plugin includes *only* the jars which are in `runtime` scope as per your configuration.  You can run `mvn dependency:tree` and compare the output with the contents of your zip.

You can try setting the property `useTransitiveDependencies` to `false`. This will exclude all transitive dependencies from the zip.  But this can have unpleasant side-effects.

Comment: Thank you!
<useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
solved my problem.

Comment: Hey @Raghuram, what are some of these unpleasant side-effects of setting `useTransitiveDependencies` to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

You use the descriptor `test-service-client-with-dependencies.xml` which includes everything and the kitchen sink in the result.

Use `jar-with-dependencies` instead. That will include entry runtime dependencies (local and transient).

If that is still too much, then you can omit dependencies by declaring them as `<scope>provided</scope>` (if someone else will add them to the classpath later), `<scope>test</scope>` (if the dependency is only necessary to run the tests) or `<optional>true</optional>` if this is an optional dependency.